# Guava reverse source odd generic syntax

Tags: java, guava

```
 /**
   * Returns a reversed view of the specified list. For example, {@code
   * Lists.reverse(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))} returns a list containing {@code 3,
   * 2, 1}. The returned list is backed by this list, so changes in the returned
   * list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa. The returned list supports
   * all of the optional list operations supported by this list.
   *
   * <p>The returned list is random-access if the specified list is random
   * access.
   *
   * @since Guava release 07
   */

  public static <T> List<T> reverse(List<T> list) {
    if (list instanceof ReverseList) {
      return ((ReverseList<T>) list).getForwardList();
    } else if (list instanceof RandomAccess) {
      return new RandomAccessReverseList<T>(list);
    } else {
      return new ReverseList<T>(list);
    }
```

I have never seen this syntax before:

```
 public static <T> List<T> reverse(List<T> list)
```

What exactly does `<T> List<T>` mean?  I thought it would be:

```
 public static List<T> reverse(List<T> list)
```

Comment: This is covered by the Java Generics tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html

Comment: @MattBall I quite disagree with that; this tutorial does not cover the _scope_ of generics, which is the crucial point here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your supposed code:

```
public static List<T> reverse(List<T> list)
```

would not even compile.

Why? Because the `T` entity, the `T` generic type, is unknown to the compiler.

When we are in the context of a method, if you declare a generic type, it has to come from somewhere. In the declaration you propose, *unless the enclosing class declares that `T`*, there is nothing the compiler can relate it to.

And when you are in the context of a static class with only utility functions, this class will certainly not be generic; hence the need to tell the compiler that "hey, this method has to have a generic type to it, and it is called `T` here". But it could be called `MEH`:

```
public static <MEH> List<MEH> reverse(List<MEH> list)
```

In essence, the rules are:

- if this is a method *linked to an instance of a generic class itself*, you can freely reuse the class' generic type declaration in methods without having to redeclare a generic type (this is why, for instance, the `.iterator()` method of a `Collection` does not have to redeclare a generic type: `Collection` already declares it);
- if, on the other hand, this method cannot be linked to an instance of a particular class (which is the case for static methods in general), you have to tell that method that a generic type exists which this method's return type and/or argument(s) should take into account.

Since you are talking about Guava, let us take another example from Guava itself: [`Closer`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Closer.html). You create an instance by calling:

```
final Closer closer = Closer.create();
```

Then this method has a `.register()` method which takes, as an argument, "any type which implements `Closeable`". The prototype of this method is:

```
public <C extends Closeable> C register(C closeable)
```

You will notice that the `Closer` class itself is not generic; its `.register()` method, however, *does* have a generics-bound argument: it requires that `C`, by the virtues of its declaration, must implement (in this case)/extend `Closeable`.

Both the argument and return type of this method happen to be that `C`, which is why you can submit, for instance, a `FileInputStream` as such:

```
final FileInputStream in; // implements Closeable

try {
    in = closer.register(new FileInputStream("meh"));
    // etc
```

Answer (score 8):

The first `<T>` shows that it's a [generic method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4), introducing `T` as a [type variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4). Don't forget that `Lists` itself isn't a generic type - so if it *were* just

```
public static List<T> reverse(List<T> list)
```

... what would you expect `T` to refer to?

See the [Java Generics FAQ entry for generic methods](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedMethods.html) for more information.

Comment: While I agree with the links, it does not explain the core of the matter. In fact, it has required a lot of time for me to understand that generics also had a scope; which is the core of the matter here.

Answer (score 1):

As @JonSkeet explained the *compiler semantics*, I'll just add a free text explanation here of *what is it for, anyway*.

You use this syntax when you want to force the elements of the returned `List<T>` to be of the same type as the elements of the method argument `List<T> list` <sub>(or, for that matter, to force any correalation between the returned type and one, or more, of the arguments types)</sub>.